# AWS ElasticBeanstalk - S3. Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I am using elasticbeanstalk for my nodejs app. I am trying to upload objects to a S3 Bucket and also trying to read objects and I am getting `AccessDenied` error.
The wired thing is that from my local I can perform those operations. So I think the problem is not with the IAM user. But with the policy in the bucket, but I am not sure.
I added a policy in the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddCannedAcl",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/myuser",
                    "arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        ],               
        "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But still can't make it work. I alse made everything public (What I don't want) just to test, and even like this can't upload or read objects.

Could anyone help me with this. I find the roles and policies really difficult to understand in aws. Also is there any tutorial or guide to study out there so I can improve my skills regarding this topic?. I always struggle with permission issues in aws.

Error:

```
Error: AccessDenied: Access Denied

async uploadFileToS3(params: any) {
    try {
        const s3UploadResult = await this.s3.upload(params).promise();

        return s3UploadResult;

    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

---

```
const params = {
                Bucket: 'my-bucket',
                Key: `${new Date()}.pdf`,
                Body: req.files ? req.files.file.data : file.buffer,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            const result = await this.awsService.uploadFileToS3(params);
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How exactly are you testing the access? Have you used AWS CLI? What is its form?

Comment: mm I don't know what do you mean by testing the access. I am just trying to uplaod the image. I didn't use the aws cli for this case. I updated the policy on aws console.

Comment: Your resoruce should be `"arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"`

Comment: Yes, I have it like this. I updated my question with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

double check all policies actions, when you delcare:

```yaml
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuild"
```

you are allowing actions on the bucket itself,

and not "in it" or "on the objects inside it"

to allow actions inside the bucket you should use:

```yaml
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybuild/*"
```

in case you need both, you can update your policy to:

```yaml
"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybuild","arn:aws:s3:::mybuild/*"]
```

few examples of typical use cases for bucket policies:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html

for learning, i highly recommend these articles:

- https://hamzahabdulla1.medium.com/aws-iam-identity-vs-resource-policy-abfe099e14d1
- https://jayendrapatil.com/aws-iam-roles-vs-resource-based-policies/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html

Comment: Thanks for your response!. I added the /* in the Resource, but still getting the same error. I will updated my question with the params I am passing to the method upload and the method, maybe that can help.

Comment: Ok I was missing something, in the end I needed to add "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybuild","arn:aws:s3:::mybuild/*"]. Thanks a lot!!